# How to get the latest state value? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple custom hooks created below. My problem is, the state seems does not updating.

The console always logs *1*, when I call `goToNextIndex`

```
const useTag = () => {
    const [tagIndex, setTagIndex] = useState(0);

    const goToNextIndex = () => {
        const updatedIndex = tagIndex + 1;
        console.log(updatedIndex);
        setTagIndex(updatedIndex);
    };
    
    return {
        tagIndex,
        goToNextIndex,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be for the consumer of `useTag` to properly respond to changes of the `goToNextIndex` function, so it doesn't have a stale closure - for example, by always using the prop value, instead of using only the value on mount, which would become out of date:

```js
const useTag = () => {
    const [tagIndex, setTagIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const goToNextIndex = () => {
        const updatedIndex = tagIndex + 1;
        console.log(updatedIndex);
        setTagIndex(updatedIndex);
    };
    
    return {
        tagIndex,
        goToNextIndex,
    };
}

const App = () => {
    const { tagIndex, goToNextIndex } = useTag();
    return <button onClick={goToNextIndex}>{tagIndex}</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

This method would be preferable when possible, since the code is as clean as it can be - often it's possible, but occasionally it wouldn't be, if asynchronous code is involved.

Another way would be to log inside the `setTagIndex` callback:

```js
const useTag = () => {
    const [tagIndex, setTagIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const goToNextIndex = () => {
        setTagIndex((mostCurrentIndex) => {
            const updatedIndex = mostCurrentIndex + 1;
            console.log(updatedIndex);
            return updatedIndex;
        });
    };
    
    return {
        tagIndex,
        goToNextIndex,
    };
}

const App = () => {
    const { tagIndex, goToNextIndex } = useTag();
    return <button onClick={goToNextIndex}>{tagIndex}</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: we have same implementation in your first answer. i wonder it does not work in my end.

Comment: Your code must be different *somewhere* - you're using the value on mount instead of updating as the prop changes. Can you edit a live Stack Snippet into your question? Or, have a link to a full reproducible example of your problem? Github, codesandbox, etc?

Comment: ahh no need. yeah. your right sir. i check it in my custom keyboard. thanks.